# Read file that is ignored using browser Javascript

Tags: javascript

So if you have something like this

```
<script type='text/undefined_type' src='hello.js'></script>
```

the browser would ignore the `hello.js` file [tested]. But how can you read the content of this ignored file using Javascript and only Javascript?

I tried this:

```
var hypeScriptFiles = new Array();
var allTag;
//get all script file
allTag = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (i=0;i<allTag.length;i++) {
    if(allTag[i].getAttribute('type')) {
        hypeScriptFiles.push('found one');
        console.log(allTag[i].getAttribute('type'));
    } else {
        hypeScriptFiles.push('nope');
    }
}
```

But in fact that the browser ignores this.

- nothing appears in the console
- something should have been logged [script line 8]

Comment: Not sure what you are attempting with your code, if you need to read in that file, you will need to use AJAX or the new javascript File API.

Comment: yes we can do ajax. I need the browser to ignore that file for specific use. But i need a way to make sure the script tag that link that file have a specific attr and then deal with the content of the file

Comment: What do you mean by "deal with the content of the file"? Do you need it read in and evaluated as javascript?

Comment: deal with it as a text file and read the content of it

Comment: not necessary a .js file

Comment: nope, because it's `text/undefine_type` i cant find the script tag using js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
for(var i in scripts)
{
    if (scripts[i].type === 'text/undefined_type')
    {
        var fileName = scripts[i].src;
        alert(fileName); // AJAX request here (no cross-domain)
    }
}
```

works for me

Comment: it worked, only that it doesn't see my `text/undefined_type` script tag, I think it has been ignore

Comment: got 4 script tag in index.html, one is text/javascript, three are text/undefine_type. Used your script and try console.log(scripts.length); and in the console, it's 1 not 4

Comment: I guess that's browser dependent. It works on Chrome. `Type` attribute must be a valid MIME type as the specification say - so the browser can just ignore it if it's not. You're probably trying to make a script language parsed in javascript. I don't think that's the safe way to embed such a script. Will be better to just include some bootstrap javascript snippet or else - different browser may treat this differently - there's no standard for this

Comment: what do you mean include bootstrap javascript snippet?

Comment: I meant to just type something like: `<script>hype('hello.js')</script>` everytime and the `hype` function will just create an element you're now trying to get

Comment: ok that give me an idea, thanks (check answer for that :))